# How to configure multiple datasources across projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm looking to build an app using Spring Boot and Spring Data (RELEASE 1.1.3) around a static data source (obtained from a 3rd party) which would effectively provide an API around said data, from which I can build a frontend, but could also be included as a dependency in other projects (to provide access to the static data) I've managed to achieve the API portion using the @RepositoryRestResource annotations, but am struggling with the latter.

Example classes:
**Item Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invTypes")
public class Item {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "typeID", nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "typeName")
  private String name;

  //Remainder ommitted
}
```

**ItemDao**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "items", path = "items")
public interface ItemDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item, Integer> {

  Item findById(@Param("id") int id);

  Item findByName(@Param("name") String name);

  List<Item> findByNameContains(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Basically I'd like to package this as a jar for use in another project, such that I can configure 2 databases (one being the static data source, and the other being related to the new project)

I've managed to package the static data project and include it as a dependency in another pom.xml, however as the new project also uses a database the imported static data jar defaults to whichever database is configured in the new project. This results in an error like:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxException: Table 'new_project.invtypes' doesn't exist
```

(This being because the new project is configured to use the 'new_project' database, as well as being configured to use Hibernates ImprovedNamingStrategy)

A colleague mentioned about configuring both databases in the new project's application.properties - however I haven't had much luck with this approach. I've tried changing the prefix of the datasource properties for the static project that are picked up by spring so that both databases could be configured (Using the guide here: http://xantorohara.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html), however it would seem that both projects use the same datasource (My apologies if I've got this all wrong)

The configuration for the static project then became:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_static")
class DataSourceConfig extends TomcatDataSourceConfiguration {
  @Bean(name = "dsStatic")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return super.dataSource();
  }

  @Bean(name = "jdbcStatic")
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsStatic) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsStatic);
  }
}
```

The properties for the approach above ended up becoming, but resulting in the same error as before:

```
# Configured properties for the new project
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/new_projct
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Configured properties for the static data jar
spring.ds_static.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/static_data
spring.ds_static.username=dbuser
spring.ds_static.password=password
spring.ds_static.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

How do I include and configure a jar to connect to it's own database instead of the database of the project that is including it as a dependency? Do I need to perform some configuration in the static data project to force it to connect to a datasource that I decide?

Thanks for any help, if you need extra information I'd be happy to provide it

Comment: It's not really clear what you want, and what you did, or what went wrong when you tried it. Do you need 2 DataSources in the final compound app, or just one?

Comment: Hi, I've tried to update it with some more information and to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Do both projects use JPA? Can you show the DataSource configuration for them both?

Comment: Yes they do, but that's the thing - I'm currently using the default spring data configuration that scans for properties prefixed 'spring.datasource'. The most configuration I've attempted so far is to change the prefix for the static data project (now included in the main question)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a custom entity manager factory in the "static" jar (e.g. see [docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-two-entity-managers)), as well as your custom datasource. After you have a custom entity manager factory you need to declare `@EnableJpaRepositories` and explicitly refer to the bean id of your entity manager factor.